# Export table in excel and read it in in pandas

Tags: pandas, html-table, download

In this website:
https://www.iadb.org/en/transparency/sanctioned-firms-and-individuals
there is the following table:

[image]

In pandas, I need to:

1. download the table (see where it says: Export to excel)
2. read in the table

Or, alternatively:

1. read in the table directly from the website.

Can anyone help me please?